# Alternate Icon in iOS 10.3: avoid notification dialog for icon change

Tags: ios, ios10.3

I'm using this new feature and when the change is made with an active application, a notification dialog is displayed saying that icon has been modified.
How to disable this dialog ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible - this alert is shown by the system. Not displaying it could lead to potential abuse.

Answer (score 16):

Adding to [Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789042/7214895) Swift 5 rewrite of [Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730130/9850339) answer (as I don't have the reputation to comment).

For the default icon we need to pass nil, so iconName should be an optional.

```
func setApplicationIconName(_ iconName: String?) {
        if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIApplication.supportsAlternateIcons)) && UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons {
            
            typealias setAlternateIconName = @convention(c) (NSObject, Selector, NSString?, @escaping (NSError) -> ()) -> ()
            
            let selectorString = "_setAlternateIconName:completionHandler:"
            
            let selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)
            let imp = UIApplication.shared.method(for: selector)
            let method = unsafeBitCast(imp, to: setAlternateIconName.self)
            method(UIApplication.shared, selector, iconName as NSString?, { _ in })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind making use of private method, you can try the following code.

```
- (void)lc_setAlternateIconName:(NSString*)iconName
{
    //anti apple private method call analyse
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(supportsAlternateIcons)] && 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] supportsAlternateIcons])
    {
        NSMutableString *selectorString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
        [selectorString appendString:@"_setAlternate"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"IconName:"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"completionHandler:"];

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
        IMP imp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] methodForSelector:selector];
        void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
        if (func)
        {
            func([UIApplication sharedApplication], selector, iconName, ^(NSError * _Nullable error) {});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great.. will they reject the app?

Comment: My apps aren't been rejected, so you can have a try. Variable selectorString is  anti 
 code static analysis.

Comment: how do you convert this to Swift 5 @Robert

Comment: Scanbot is doing it in their app, so I guess it should be fine to use for now

Answer (score 7):

Rewrote [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730130/9850339)'s answer in Swift. The app hasn't been rejected as well.

```
func setApplicationIconName(_ iconName: String) {
        if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIApplication.supportsAlternateIcons)) && UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons {
            
            typealias setAlternateIconName = @convention(c) (NSObject, Selector, NSString, @escaping (NSError) -> ()) -> ()
            
            let selectorString = "_setAlternateIconName:completionHandler:"
            
            let selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)
            let imp = UIApplication.shared.method(for: selector)
            let method = unsafeBitCast(imp, to: setAlternateIconName.self)
            method(UIApplication.shared, selector, iconName as NSString, { _ in })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm it works in iOS16, too. waiting to Store approval..

Comment: Did you get the approve?

Comment: approved, BUT seems not working in iPad.. we will investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

From the above Answer from [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916997/robert)

```
- (void)lc_setAlternateIconName:(NSString*)iconName
{
    //anti apple private method call analyse
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(supportsAlternateIcons)] && 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] supportsAlternateIcons])
    {
        NSMutableString *selectorString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
        [selectorString appendString:@"_setAlternate"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"IconName:"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"completionHandler:"];

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
        IMP imp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] methodForSelector:selector];
        void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
        if (func)
        {
            func([UIApplication sharedApplication], selector, iconName, ^(NSError * _Nullable error) {});
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't make the line

```
void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
```

For me it had to be

```
void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void (*)(id, SEL, id, id))imp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    func setAppIcon(_ appIcon: String?) {
        typealias setAlternateIconName = @convention(c) (
            NSObject, Selector, NSString?, @escaping (NSError?) -> Void
        ) -> Void
        
        let selector = NSSelectorFromString(
            "_setAlternateIconName:completionHandler:"
        )

        if let imp = method(for: selector) {
            let method = unsafeBitCast(imp, to: setAlternateIconName.self)
            method(self, selector, appIcon as NSString?, { _ in })
        }
    }
}
```