# Alternate Icon - Disable alert on icon change (UPDATE)

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications, appicon

This is an update to this outdates question: [Alternate Icon in iOS 10.3: avoid notification dialog for icon change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356570/alternate-icon-in-ios-10-3-avoid-notification-dialog-for-icon-change)

---

```
func setAppIcon(Type: String) {
    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
       UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(Type)
    }
}
```

With the few lines above it is possible to change the Appicon dynamically, the feature was added with iOS 10.3.

The code above is working fine but every time the **app icon** changed iOS triggers an alert like this:

[image: img]

> So is there a way to get rid of this alert? (I know that apple could reject application for disabling user-information but I'd like to use it just for test purposes)

Any help would be SUPER appreciated, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code, however, it is written with Objective-c. It makes use of private method, I guess that you will never mind.

```
- (void)lc_setAlternateIconName:(NSString*)iconName
{
    //anti apple private method call analyse
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(supportsAlternateIcons)] && 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] supportsAlternateIcons])
    {
        NSMutableString *selectorString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
        [selectorString appendString:@"_setAlternate"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"IconName:"];
        [selectorString appendString:@"completionHandler:"];

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
        IMP imp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] methodForSelector:selector];
        void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
        if (func)
        {
            func([UIApplication sharedApplication], selector, iconName, ^(NSError * _Nullable error) {});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great.. will they reject the app?

Comment: My apps aren't been rejected, so you can have a try. Variable selectorString is  anti 
 code static analysis.

Comment: How do you convert the `void (*func)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
        if (func)
        {
            func([UIApplication sharedApplication], selector, iconName, ^(NSError * _Nullable error) {});
        }` to swift?

Comment: Solution worked great for me, wasn't able to convert the final bit too swift. but used a good old fashion bridge file and worked fine

Comment: Here my swift version. Problem is, that the alert still shows :/ Maybe I made a mistake and someone has a better idea:
`let selector = #selector(UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName)
        let imp = UIApplication.shared.method(for: selector)

        typealias ClosureType = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector, String?, ((Error?) -> Void)? ) -> Void
        let curry : ClosureType = unsafeBitCast(imp, to: ClosureType.self)
        
        curry(UIApplication.shared, selector, iconName, nil)`

Comment: If they catch you using a private api you get a warning, get caught more than once you run a risk of getting banned.